# Offline speech recognition choices from CSV with folder nickname, and relative path C#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech

I am curious if it's possible with C# and system speech to read from a csv where column 1 is a folder nickname and column 2 is it's path. So I can say 'open 'nickname from column 1' folder' and it opens the relative path from column 2 in explorer.
I know how to do this if all this information is within the program (as shown in code below) but not reading 2 columns from a csv that can be easily updated. I could see this being very useful for custom macros too

I shouldn't ask about parsing a csv specifically, so how can I 'get' the array number that was chosen by system speech and use that same number to get the folder path from a second array.
If that's not the most efficient way I'm very interested to know other ways

In this basic example the csv would be 2 rows and columns like this

```
Temp,C:\Temp
Main,C:\Main
```

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace WinFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine listener = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listener.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            listener.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices("C", "open main folder"))));
            listener.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(Speech_recognize);
        }

        private void Speech_recognize(object? sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            string Speech = e.Result.Text;
            if (Speech == "open temp folder")
            {
                
                Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"C:\Temp");

            }
            if (Speech == "open main folder")
            {
                
                Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"C:\Main");

            }
        }

        private void listen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listener.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            listen.Enabled = false;
            stop.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listener.RecognizeAsyncCancel();
            listen.Enabled = true;
            stop.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Break the problem domwn into parts, the system speech component is always the same, the only difference is to read and parse the information from a file and store as needed (A string array for example). What have you tried? Which part of opening a CSV did you get stuck on? You either read in the whole file then loop it, or you read one line at a time with a loop and store the contents as needed.

Comment: I am stuck with how to make it know the relative directory from column 2 based on the recognized word it found from column 1 if that makes sense. I can only wrap my head around hard coding in the file nickname and directory similar to what was done in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OyWhAqW_kqg

Comment: I'm also curious which of those two options would you recommend? I can't see making a memorable folder list over 100 rows

Comment: I don't want to use offsite links/videos, please edit your question to include the relevant hard code in your question, and I am sure we can offer a solution to work in with using strings from a file.

Comment: I've added a second point in my question which probably summarizes my problem better with much less code to answer. Hope it helps